# Can a single data stream be recieved by multiple bluetooth devices without interruption?

Tags: bluetooth

So i know i can make a "server" and send a data stream to multiple devices one after another. But if the data stream is same for 5 devices can they all recieve it at the same time like standard FM? I saw some protocols developed by some companies that can "do it" but they only work with big manufacturers.

Edit:

Point 1:disable pairing requirement for connection (easy to do)

Point 2:disable all slave to master communication (L2CAP?)

welp

Answer (score -1):

> But if the data stream is same for 5 devices can they all recieve it
>   at the same time like standard FM?

If your antenna emits in all directions (as per a quarter wave monopole) then once the EM field is created, any receiving antenna can receive the signal from any direction and multiple receiving antennas can do this simultaneously. This is slightly complicated by the fact that two close by receive antennas can interact with each other and create problems.

However, if the distance between receive antennas is greater than a couple of wavelengths then you should be ok.

Analogy: think of several people in a room looking at an LED turning on and off. Only those stood behind or partially shadowed by someone else my be inhibited in their view. Light is EM waves so it’s a bit closer to the truth than most analogies.

Think about broadcast radio transmitters and how many listeners there are.

However, protocols might be the sting in the tail. If the broadcaster requires some form of acknowledge that “someone” has received the message, then multiple receivers all responding together will be a problem. This can be overcome of course, like most things.

Comment: Yes and i would like to do that with bluetooth, but it is quite complicated so i need some guidance on how to do it, b-stack wise.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I downvoted because the poster is clearly asking about Bluetooth and this answer doesn't discuss it at all. The Bluetooth specification has features specifically for one-to-many broadcast communication. I'm not familiar enough with the spec to write a good answer, but BLE has had "advertising" transmission types for a long time (not supporting high enough data rate for good audio), and the recently introduced LE Audio spec has a feature intended exactly for what the OP asked.

Comment: The question said “like standard FM” and that is what I answered.